# want to show average rating and total reviews of product

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am beginner and following a tutorial to make a review products application and rather than just copy pasting the code trying to do some experiment with it to get more depth knowledge.  I have two questions regarding my app

**1)** I added some more functionality to my app and wrote some code in **includes.js** and **reviews.html** to show average rating and total review of a product .How i can show average rating and number of reviews for the product thats been clicked?

**2)** I added product categories list to show in side bar(e.g Electronics , Fashion, Books) through chrome console by adding them manually e.g like this

```
Categories.insert({name:'Eelctronics',slug:'electronics'});
```

So i have deployed this app on free meteor hosting and every time some one run this app he has to write this above code manually in chrome console to get list of categories.Even if some one clone my project from gitHub also can not see list of categories in left side bar and he also have to write the same code in console.So what is the solution for it how i can show list of categories in my side bar with out writing above code in console?

You can check gitHub [repository](https://github.com/soni1/reviewIt) for source code.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Show average rating and review count**

```
<p>Average Rating: <img class="stars" src="/img/star{{averageRating}}.png"> ({{countReviews}})</p>
```

I've moved this code into reviews.helpers section

```
Template.reviews.helpers({
  'reviews': function () {
    return Reviews.find({productId: Router.current().data()._id})
  },

  countReviews: function(){
    return Reviews.find({productId: Router.current().data()._id}).count();
  },

  averageRating: function() {
    var reviews = Reviews.find({productId: Router.current().data()._id}); //get all reviews for productId
    //var ratings = reviews.map(function(player){return player.score;}); // get just the ratings, or use _.pluck
    var ratings = _.pluck(reviews, 'ratings'); // get just the ratings i.e. [1, 5, 3, 2, 5]
    var sum = ratings.reduce(function(pv, cv){return pv + cv;}, 0);  //sum ratings i.e. 14
    var avg = sum / ratings.length;  // i.e. 2.8
    return Math.round(2.8);  // round avg to ensure only integer values are returned
  },

})
```

**2) Seed database**

[Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_startup) Add a Meteor.startup block to seed database

```
// On server startup, if the database is empty, create some initial data.
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Categories.find().count() === 0) {
      Categories.insert({name:'Electronics',slug:'electronics'});
      Categories.insert({name:'Fashion',slug:'fashion'});
      Categories.insert({name:'Books',slug:'books'});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please also help me with first question , how to show total reviews and average rating for the product thats been clicked ? @JeremyK

Comment: averageRating helper function is still not showing average rating . Can you please also explain the function how is it working ? @Jeremyk

Comment: sure I'll break it down into more steps.

Comment: i have another project and almost same code except field name is rating not ratings in reviews collection to get average rating but i am getting error Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rating' of null @JeremyK

Comment: Did this answer your original question?  If so, you should accept the answer.  If you have new questions, post new questions.

Comment: that error would indicate that the Reviews collection is empty though.  This may be a timing issue with your subscriptions, or due to the filter conditions.

Comment: i found the reason as just using find will return the cursor and we can not use _pluck on cursor so we have to use fetch with find so it can return as an array. But the problem is though i am not getting previous error but it is still not returning proper average for example if a recipe has total 15 rating of total 5 reviews so average should be 3 but its is returning me 2289.